# Testing by spinning up db's as needed or mocking?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js

I'm starting a new node project and i'd like to have maximum test coverage. I'm trying to figure out the best way to test things that hit a database or call another REST service.

I've dabbled with sinon.js for mock/spys/stubs, but that stuff seems to get confusing to me pretty quickly.

I was thinking of using some in memory node data store to setup and populate with data, run my tests, then tear down the in memory data store. Basically something similar to how travis-ci works.

As far as hitting web services I think i'll still have to mock/spy/stub those out.

How are other people handling stuff like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For BDD the test specs should be fast. If the tests are fast it will allow you to develop fast.

You are not going to test other REST services, you are going to test how your code behaves on using those REST services.

Mocking the REST services is always a good idea as it speeds the specs execution.

For specs related to DB read and write, it always good to run a DB locally and you can use `beforeEach` and `afterEach` to insert and remove data from DB.

For automating start and stop of db, add `pretest` and `posttest` command under `scripts` in `package.json`

**Conclusion:** 
I would mock the REST services and run a local DB just for testing. This will allow me to run the specs fast.

Using `grunt watch` with this and hit save, BAM!!!, you know if your specs passes or not.